# React scrollTop=0 for componentDidMount not working:

Tags: reactjs, scrollto

I have the following component and result from the console log. I'm getting no error for my scrollTop=500, however when I refresh the page doesn't adjust accordingly. Thanks.

```
componentDidMount: function () {
  console.log(this);
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).scrollTop=500;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the code that you've posted. Move the log to a new code block and fix indentation (or remove it altogether). It's hard to say what could be wrong with so little info, you might want to create a jsfiddle reproducing the issue.

Comment: Could it be possible that `this` does not have sufficient height to scroll just after `componentDidMount`? One possible reason could be that you are waiting for data to render which comes in after `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 2):

this happens to me too.
In one point of the app the solution I found was to set a `setTimeout` function:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.scrollTop=500;      
  })
}
```

But the same solution didn't work on another component.
In that case the solution was to set `history.scrollRestoration` to `manual`

```
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
  history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```

I hope someone will find something more consistent and less empiric.

Comment: Thank you! setTimout() worked for me. Had a bug in Firefox only in which scrollTop or scrollToTop wouldn't fire without setTimeout().

Comment: Also, in case others have the issue, I had to add a slight delay. In my case, a 100ms delay was sufficient: `setTimeout(() => { ... }, 100);`